# how to do sales receipt

Tags: arrays, struct

I have a marketplace. I wanted to make a sales receipt for each item sold. The sales receipt will indicate
`address_receipt`,`nameOfGood`, `amountOfGood`,`Price`, `sumPrice`,`address_transaction`. What should I effectively implement through? Through an array? in solidity maybe arrays in an array? or through a struct? I need that when the buyer's address is given at the entrance, his sales receipts should be displayed. thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could generate a contract for each item sold and store the sale info on a struct in a more readable and accessible way.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

contract MarketplaceContract{    

  struct SalesReceipt{
        address  address_receipt
        string   nameOfGood 
        uint     amountOfGood 
        uint     Price  
        uint     sumPrice
        address  address_transaction
    }
}
```